# Getting best performance out of a virtual machine

Tags: memory, performance, cpu, vmware-workstation

Host Machine:

- Windows 8.1
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz 2.40 GHz
- RAM: 24GB
- System Type: 64 bit OS, x84 processor

What I've been running as a virtual machine

- Windows 7
- 12GB Memory
- 2 processors, 1 core per processor

I have not been getting very good performance out of it at all. My vm CPU seems to constantly stay at 100% and everything is extremely slow. What other combination of settings would someone recommend I try?

Edit: I'm running my virtual machine off of an external, SSD via USB 3.0

Comment: change it to 1 CPU and 2 cores!

Comment: What's your hypervisor? Also, the USB 3.0 MIGHT be a bottleneck, depending

Comment: I've changed it to 1CPUx2 cores and it seemed fine on startup, but when I opened Chrome, it shot back up to 100% and stayed there. CPU 100% and Physical Memory 19%. Where would I find the hypervisor? I don't see where that is.

Comment: 2CPU x 2 Core seems to be working fairly well...